# Selecting related fields with GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm new to Golang coming from a python background so trying to understand the new and different concepts.
I'm trying to create related fields and then select them from the database.

Models:

```
type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

type CreditCard struct {
    gorm.Model
    Number    int
    Company   Company
    CompanyId uint
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name         string
    CreditCard   CreditCard
    CreditCardID uint
}
```

Create tables and rows and select from db

```
common.DB.AutoMigrate(
    &Company{},
    &CreditCard{},
    &User{},
)

user := User{
    Name:       "Alice",
    CreditCard: CreditCard{Number: 123456, Company: Company{Name: "Bank A"}},
}

common.DB.Create(&user)

var retrivedUser User
var creditCard CreditCard
var company Company
common.DB.First(&retrivedUser, 1).Related(&creditCard).Related(&company)

fmt.Println("user name", retrivedUser.Name)
fmt.Println("creditcard number", retrivedUser.CreditCard.Number)
fmt.Println("creditcard number related", creditCard.Number)
fmt.Println("company name", retrivedUser.CreditCard.Company.Name)
fmt.Println("company name related", company.Name)
```

This prints:

```
user name Alice
creditcard number 0
creditcard number related 123456
company name 
company name related
```

Two questions:

1. Why do I need to select `Related` creditCard to a separate variable instead of using the dot notation?
2. I get error `invalid association []` on the `Related` company, and neither dot notation or Related work. How do I get this back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Auto-Preloading), you need to set `auto_preload` to `true` for Auto Preloading to work. So changing the line where you retrieve the user to:

```golang
common.DB.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).First(&retrivedUser, 1)
```

should give you the expected result.

---

On a side note, **never** ignore the errors. You can always append `.Error` to almost every operation in `gorm` and check the returned error. For example:

```golang
err = common.DB.AutoMigrate(...).Error
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

err = common.DB.Create(&user).Error
// Check for err
err = common.DB.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).First(&retrivedUser, 1).Error
// Check for err
```

Comment: Thanks, so much easier than Preload every related table table. Thanks for the `.Error` tip too!

Comment: Do you know if this doing a join or another query (if using a relational db)?